# Is using of CAMERA allowed in Islam?

Tags: halal-haram, hadith

Assalaam-O-Alaikum Wa Rahmatullahi Wa Barakaatuhu!!

Prophet Muhammad(Peace Be Upon Him) prohibited to making the photos/pictures of humans and animals.

> The Prophet said, 'Angels do not enter a house in which there are dogs or pictures. (Sahih-Al-Bukhari, 7.833, Narrated by Abu Talha)

```
Hadith 7.834 (Al-Bukhari Hadith)
```

Making of pictures are not allowed in Islam.

> "The people who will receive the severest punishment from Allah will be the picture makers.'" (Narrated by Muslim)

Hadith 7.838 (Al-Bukhari Hadith)

Then how the modern scholars are allowed to use the CAMERA??

Comment: You are posting hadith in regards to painting/drawings but asking about Photos/Cameras, which is it?

Comment: **<deleted comments>**. Comments are not for discussion. [chat] _is_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is very valid and it is difficult to find references to support the technology of camera.

Al Azhar academy though is renowned for its research in this area and has separated camera from drawing by referring camera as a tool to capture a particular moment rather than drawing.

As photo is real and as long as it is not photoshopped it can't be put into the category of drawing because drawing is fake and Allah will say to the man who made the drawing to give it life but as photo is real and man didn't create it but only captured it so many modern scholars excludes it from drawing.

Photographs can also be seen as similar to seeing reflection in a pond of water but only this time it is still and captured and I can only make this the core for discussion as camera was not available in ancient times. Maybe editing or adding anything to original photo might make these points weak.

Similarly many rigid scholars have also approved camera though they have only approved this technology due to the strict laws as photographs are used in every legal work and there is no other way so a person can take his/her photographs in such cases but in other cases these scholars recommend to play it safe by not using something which may cost our deeds as these scholars believe photographs are same as drawing.

Moreover photos of animals specially dogs should not be placed in homes and there is no flexibility in such case.

Finally, My own opinion is to try and play safe by using the technology when needed.

Comment: Please state some source when you answer questions :)

Comment: i think photos of persons also should not be placed on walls in homes in visible or high places because that automatically function quite like idols because they are constantly reminded and if it is at high place it is automatically felt, in some degree, like big and strong thing.

Comment: Do you know there were good artists in past which could draw actual image of people? The drawing would be same as with cameras today but there would be just a small difference. If taking or making pictures were valid, then Muhammad would have sketched His image through some experience artist to teach us about its validity!!

Comment: @RehanUllah That small difference is huge in my eyes and if you are not clear about it you can view the stance of Al Azhar institution of Egypt which has notably approved the technology. Finally I myself do not fully approve it and feel that the technology should only be used in case of need.

Comment: @Imran, +1 but You should add your last point In your answer there are many scholar that are against using camera and consider it same as drawing a picture..

Comment: @Musk sorry, I didn't state the source but try finding the opinion of "Al Azhar school of thought" which is in Egypt if you want to know more. I have read books of it but don't know if it is also on the web as I haven't tried finding it out but please you can search on it and paste the link if you find it. I will try as well.

Comment: @ali786, I will add once you tell me your opinion. I have met some scholars who state photographs same as drawing but in many occasions such as national identity card or passports you need to have photographs. In these cases these scholars too have shown flexibility by stating that taking photographs in such cases can be allowed.

Answer (score 0):

It is allowed to use Camera (take videos) or take Photos in Islam. Let me point that videos are nothing more than a sequence of photos.

Taking Videos/Pictures is an actual representation of what you are seeing (like in your eyes) you are not drawing anything or creating anything new.

What you are referring to in the Hadith's posted are hand drawn pictures, which I believe are also OK but won't cover the reason since it wasn't your question has been extensively asked before:

https://islam.stackexchange.com/search?q=drawing

Comment: An answer should have proper references. How can you say taking photos are valid!! Do you have any proof? If yes, mention it here. If not, then also put it here!

Comment: @RehanUllah The OP did not ask for references. If photos are Haram then by inheritance TV/Cameras are also haram (read my answer to see why). I doubt you will find any scholar that says tv recordings are haram.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, Taking pictures / video using camera is okay instead of drawing by hands, this is because,

We are not creating with camera (like drawing a non-existing thing with our imagination which may mislead others interpretation), instead capturing the existing one (the one created by Allah.) ). Since, no one can create anything new thing in this universe, expect Allah.Hence one is prohibited from drawing (to avoid misleading others), while using the camera is fine.

Correct me if my learning's are wrong

Allah knows the best.

Comment: You are not supposed to use pbuh in allah name i think